# Problem using pgRouting 2.0

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I follow this great post:[pgRouting 2.0 for Windows quick guide](http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/), and I have loaded the test data from [GeoJSON](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:OEFFLINIENOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json), like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to load this layer into my database, and my DB manager doesn't look the same as in Anita's post:
[image]

How should I do to load and test this layer into my PostGIS database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using QGIS 1.8, 2.0 adds the Import and Export buttons to the DB Manager plugin.  Without upgrading QGIS you're going to need to use another import tool to get your data into PostGIS.  You can either use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_geojson.html) to directly import your GeoJSON file, or you can right click on the layer in QGIS, save it to a shapefile then use shp2PGSQL, shp2PGSQL-gui, SPIT, or any one of a number of different shapefile to PostGIS importers.

Personally I'd upgrade QGIS to 2.0, there are tons of improvements and the direct import to PostGIS from the DB Manager window is one of my favorites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've downloaded QGIS 2.0 and I am trying its new features!